# Iterate a 3-way interaction ggplot call over combinations of 4 factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

*Disclaimer: A better title suggestion is more than welcome*

I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I iterate `ggplot2` calls over different combinations of 3 factors. I can probably describe this best based on data... *But if something is not clear, please ask / comment (English is not my primary language)*

Given a dataframe like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)

# Make up data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(16),
                 factor1 = gl(2, 1, 16), 
                 factor2 = gl(2, 2, 16),
                 factor3 = gl(2, 4, 16),
                 factor4 = gl(2, 8, 16))
```

And given the fact that 4 factors (`factor1:factor4`) make up 24 unique combinations of 3 elements, I'll call them:

- `x axis`
- `lines`
- `facets`

And store it in `p`:

```
p <- data.frame(
      permutations(4,3, c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3", "factor4")))
names<- c("x axis", "lines", "facets")
colnames(p) <- names

> head(p)
   x axis   lines  facets
1 factor1 factor2 factor3
2 factor1 factor2 factor4
3 factor1 factor3 factor2
4 factor1 factor3 factor4
5 factor1 factor4 factor2
6 factor1 factor4 factor3
```

How can I automate drawing 24 graphs so that:

- values `x axis`, `lines` and `facets` are taken from each row of `p` one by one
- `df$y` is summarised (`mean(y, na.rm=T`) across corresponding factors
- a plot is shown

If I where to do it manually the 4th plot (out of 24) would look like this:

```
p[4,]
   x axis   lines  facets
4 factor1 factor3 factor4

df %>% group_by(factor1, factor3, factor4) %>%
      summarise(y=mean(y, na.rm=T)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(y=y, x = factor1)) +
      geom_line(aes(group=factor3, color=factor3)) +
      facet_grid(~factor4)
```

While the 24th would be like this:

```
> p[24,]
    x axis   lines  facets
24 factor4 factor3 factor2

    df %>% group_by(factor4, factor3, factor2) %>%
          summarise(y=mean(y, na.rm=T)) %>% 
          ggplot(aes(y=y, x = factor4)) +
          geom_line(aes(group=factor3, color=factor3)) +
          facet_grid(~factor2)
```

Could anyone please help me out with this?

**EDIT1**

I've been able to write a `for()` loop to aggregate data, but for resons I don't understad all 24 dataframes are the same:

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
      xaxis <- as.character(p[i,1])
      lines <- as.character(p[i,2])
      facets <- as.character(p[i,3])
      colnames(df)[colnames(df) == xaxis[i]] <- "xaxis"
      colnames(df)[colnames(df) == lines[i]] <- "lines"
      colnames(df)[colnames(df) == facets[i]] <- "facets"
      print(df %>% group_by(xaxis, lines, facets) %>%
                  summarise(y=mean(y, na.rm=T)))
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider base R's `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) as an alternative to iterate elementwise through permutations dataframe.

```
p <- data.frame(permutations(4,3, c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3", "factor4")),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
         setNames(c("xaxis", "lines", "facets"))

runplots <- function(x, l, f) {      
  df2 <- df[c("y", x, l, f)] %>% 
           setNames(c("y", "xaxis", "lines", "facets"))

  print(df2 %>% 
          group_by(xaxis, lines, facets) %>%
          summarise(y=mean(y, na.rm=T)) %>%
          ggplot(aes(y=y, x = xaxis)) +
            geom_line(aes(group=lines, color=lines)) +
            facet_grid(~facets))
}

plot_list <- Map(runplots, p$xaxis, p$lines, p$facets)
```

And since you retain a list of plots with output of `Map`, you can use the object for continued use elsewhere. Even remove `print` and call plots as shown below:

```
# BY INDEX
plot_list[[1]]
plot_list[[2]]
...

# BY NAME (AFTER RENAMING LIST)
names(plot_list) <- gsub("factor", "f", paste(p$xaxis, p$lines, p$facets, sep="_"))
plot_list$f1_f2_f3
plot_list$f1_f2_f4
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok... it took me half day of trial and error but eventually got it working

**Make up data**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gtools)


set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(16),
                 factor1 = gl(2, 1, 16), 
                 factor2 = gl(2, 2, 16),
                 factor3 = gl(2, 4, 16),
                 factor4 = gl(2, 8, 16))

p <- data.frame(
      permutations(4,3, c("factor1", "factor2", "factor3", "factor4")))
names<- c("xaxis", "lines", "facets")
colnames(p) <- names
```

**Make plots**

```
for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
      xaxis <- as.character(p[i,1])
      lines <- as.character(p[i,2])
      facets <- as.character(p[i,3])
      df2 <- df %>% rename(xaxis= colnames(df)[colnames(df) == xaxis],
                         lines= colnames(df)[colnames(df) == lines],
                         facets= colnames(df)[colnames(df) == facets])
      print(df2 %>% 
                  group_by(xaxis, lines, facets) %>%
                  summarise(y=mean(y, na.rm=T)) %>%
                  ggplot(aes(y=y, x = xaxis)) +
                  geom_line(aes(group=lines, color=lines)) +
                  facet_grid(~facets))
}
```

I'll leave this as an open answer and if anyone would like to show me anything more elegant (just for the sake of my curiosity) I'm more than happy to accept it.